# Is the standard matrix of an invertible linear map also invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $L : \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}^n$ is an invertible linear mapping, then is $[L]$ also invertible?

I'm having difficulty with this practice question. Please give me any hints or give me a place to start.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the result that if $L$ and $M$ are linear operators on $\mathbb R^n$, then the matrix of $L \circ M$ is $[L][M]$?

Comment: Yeah, its a theorem in the textbook.

Comment: This exercise relates the "invertiblity" of a linear mapping to *invertibility* of a matrix representing that mapping (with respect to a "standard basis").  What characterization(s) of an invertible matrix do you know that might be helpful (including, for example, the definition)?

Comment: Then you can observe that $L \circ L^{-1} = id$, where $id$ is the identity map on $\mathbb R^n$. Taking matrix representations of both sides gives us $[L][L^{-1}] = I$. Similarly, $[L^{-1}][L] = I$. Hence $[L]$ is invertible.

Comment: If $[L]$ was not invertible, then it would be easy to show that $L$ is not invertible.

Comment: How do you know that  L∘L−1=id?

Comment: @TimWeah, that is (half of) the definition of invertible. (The other half is $L^{-1} \circ L = \mathrm{id}$.)

Comment: I thought the definition of invertibility was that if L is an invertible mapping, then there exists a linear mapping M with appropriate domain and codomain such that L of M of x = x. So I guess my question is how do we know that the inverse of L is L^-1. Oh wait nvm typing that sentence made me understand it. Lmfao

Comment: @Bundo or to anyone else, is it ok to just prove that [L][L^-1]=I or do we also need to show that [L^-1][L]=I?

Comment: @TimWeah: It depends on your context. Showing that $AB=BA=I$ is definitely sufficient to show that $B$ is the inverse of $A$, but, for example, there is a result that shows that if $A,B$ are square and $AB=I$ then $BA=I$. So, it depends on which results you have access to.

Comment: @copper.hat thanks. So I've been kind of working on this from the information here, and I got to [L][L^-1]x=x. But I dont know what to do after. Am I on the right track?

Comment: @TimWeah: Yes. It is mainly an exercise in keeping track of the relationships. Essentially $L$ and $[L]$ represent the same thing, but the mapping back and forth between representations needs a clear head.

Comment: @TimWeah: If you show that $Ax = x$ for all $x$ then we have $A=I$.

Comment: @copper.hat I'm really sorry I'm just getting started with lin. alg. Could you explain how you could go from [L][L^-1]x=x to [L][L^-1]=I ?

Comment: @TimWeah: No problem, it is daunting at first (and sometimes later too). It is just a definition, the identity map $I$ is defined as $Ix = x$. Also, if $Ax=Bx$ for all $x$ we write $A = B$. In your case, you have $(AB)x = x$ for all $x$ so we have $AB=I$ (where $A=[L], B=[L^{-1}]$ in this case).

Answer (score 1):

If $L$ is invertible and $\{e_1, \ldots, e_n\}$ is the canonical basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $\{Le_1, \ldots, Le_n\}$ is also a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

By definition, the columns of $[L]$ are precisely $\{Le_1, \ldots, Le_n\}$. Hence $\operatorname{rank} [L] = n$ so $[L]$ is invertible.

Comment: I understand everything here except the very first impliaction. How is {Le1,…,Len}  also a basis for R^n?

Comment: @TimWeah Notice that $\{Le_1, \ldots, Le_n\}$ is linearly independent. Indeed, assume $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i Le_i = 0$. We have
$$0 =\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i Le_i = L\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i e_i\right) $$
Since $L$ is injective, we get $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i e_i = 0$ so $\alpha_1 = \cdots = \alpha_n = 0$ because $\{e_1, \ldots, e_n\}$ is linearly independent.
Hence $\{Le_1, \ldots, Le_n\}$ is linearly independent. Since $\dim \mathbb{R}^n = n$, we conclude that $\{Le_1, \ldots, Le_n\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 0):

More generally, if $V$ is a vector space with basis $\mathscr{B}=\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$, we can define the *coordinate* map $C_{\mathscr{B}}\colon V\to\mathbb{R}^n$ where
$$
C_{\mathscr{B}}(v)=\begin{bmatrix}\alpha_1\\\alpha_2\\ \vdots \\ \alpha_n\end{bmatrix}
\quad\text{if and only if}\quad
v=\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2+\dots+\alpha_nv_n
$$
It is readily seen that $C_{\mathscr{B}}$ is well defined, linear and bijective.

Now suppose $W$ is another vector space with basis $\mathscr{D}$.

> **Theorem.** *If $L\colon V\to W$ is a linear map, then there exists a unique matrix $A$ such that, for all $v\in V$,*
>   $$
> C_{\mathscr{D}}(L(v))=AC_{\mathscr{B}}(v)
> $$

Such matrix $A$ is sometimes denoted as $[L]_{\mathscr{B}}^{\mathscr{D}}$ or variations thereof.

The uniqueness stated in the theorem allows us to easily prove that if $Z$ is another vector space with basis $\mathscr{F}$, and $M\colon W\to Z$ is a linear map, then
$$
[M\circ L]_{\mathscr{B}}^{\mathscr{F}}=
[M]_{\mathscr{D}}^{\mathscr{F}}
[L]_{\mathscr{B}}^{\mathscr{D}}\tag{*}
$$

Among the basic properties of $[L]_{\mathscr{B}}^{\mathscr{D}}$ is that its rank is the same as the rank of $L$ (dimension of the image). In particular, if $L$ is invertible, then also $[L]_{\mathscr{B}}^{\mathscr{D}}$ is invertible.

Your situation is even easier, because you have $V=\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathscr{B}=\mathscr{D}$ is the standard (canonical) basis. Then, omitting to specify the bases in the associated matrix, the relation (*) becomes (where $\iota$ denotes the identity map
$$
[\iota]=[L^{-1}\circ L]=[L^{-1}][L]
$$
and it is obvious that $[\iota]$ is the identity matrix. Therefore
$$
[L^{-1}]=[L]^{-1}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$L$ is invertible $\iff [L]_{\mathcal B}$ for any basis $\mathcal B$ is invertible $\iff [L]_{\mathcal S}$ where $\mathcal S$ is the standard basis is invertible.

The easiest way to see it is that we are talking in any case about the *same* linear transformation (so it does the same thing to vectors in $\mathbb R^n$).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by standard matrix, I presume you mean the matrix
with respect to some fixed basis $b_1,...,b_n$ in the domain and codomain. Let
$c$ denote the coordinates with respect to this basis, that is,
$c(\sum_k x_k b_k ) = (x_1,...,x_n)^T$. Note that $c$ is linear and invertible, with
$c^{-1}((x_1,...,x_n)^T) = \sum_k x_k b_k $.

Then we have $[L]x = c(L(c^{-1}(x))$ (this is how $[L]$ is defined).

To show that $[L]$ is invertible, it is sufficient to show that it is injective.

Suppose $[L]x = 0$, then $c(L(c^{-1}(x)) = 0$ and hence $L(c^{-1}(x)) = 0$. Since
$L$ is invertible, we have $c^{-1}(x) = 0$ and so $x=0$.

Alternatively, note that
$[L^{-1}][L]x = c(L^{-1}(c^{-1}(c(L(c^{-1}(x)))))) = c(L^{-1}(L(c^{-1}(x))) = c(c^{-1}(x)) =x $, and so $[L^{-1}][L] = I$.